# Argument dimensions are incompatible, issue with filling_between

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am ploting 2 lines in a graph and I would like to shade the area in between, however I cannot make it happen, my data are 2 DataFrames with 365 observations.
My currently code looks like this.

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(minimos, '', maximos, '')
plt.scatter(df6x, df6, s=50, c='r', alpha=0.8)
plt.scatter(df5x, df5, s=50, c='b', alpha=0.8)
plt.legend(['High', 'Low'])
```

I have this: 
[image]

More info about the DataFrames

```
  print(type(maximos),type(minimos), type(x))
  print(maximos.shape, minimos.shape,x.shape)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
 (365, 1) (365, 1) (365, 1)
```

But I still having the issue with ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

 maximos = maximos.values
 minimos = minimos.values
 x = np.arange(0,365,1)
 x = x.reshape(365,1)
 fig = plt.figure()
 plt.plot(x, maximos, c='r', alpha=0.8)
 plt.plot(x, minimos, c='b', alpha=0.8)
 # fill between hgh and low
 ax = fig.gca()
 ax.fill_between(x, minimos, maximos, facecolor='purple')
 plt.legend(['High', 'Low'])
 plt.scatter(df6x, df6, s=50, c='r', alpha=0.8)
 plt.scatter(df5x, df5, s=50, c='b', alpha=0.8)
```

The error is in this line of code ax.fill_between(x, minimos, maximos, facecolor='purple').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use `x = x.reshape(365,1)` here. Reshaping `x` makes the argument dimensions incompatible, as the error says. Omitting that line would make the code work:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

maximos = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(365)-0.5)+40
minimos = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(365)-0.5)+0.7

x = np.arange(0,365,1)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, maximos, c='r', alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(x, minimos, c='b', alpha=0.8)

plt.fill_between(x, minimos, maximos, facecolor='purple')
plt.legend(['High', 'Low'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: with out the reshape I got this, <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(365, 1) (365, 1) (365,) and I am still unable to make it work

Comment: You would now still need to reshape the two arrays minimos and maximos to only have 1 dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fill_between`: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,365,1)
hgh = np.random.uniform(20,30,len(x))
low = np.random.uniform(-10,10, len(x))

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, hgh, c='r', alpha=0.8)
plt.plot(x, low, c='b', alpha=0.8)

# fill between hgh and low
ax = fig.gca()
ax.fill_between(x, low, hgh, facecolor='gold')

plt.legend(['High', 'Low'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This seems ok but I am not able to make it work I got a ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible, any idea why am I getting this?

Comment: It might be that the two dataframes do not share the same index. The best solution would then depend on the data, so sharing more information about the dataframes would help. In any case sharing the code that produces the error is necessary to help you.

Comment: I have added more info about the DataFrames, can I add something more?